# Affective method of handling colour on dynamic choropleth legend in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

After reading the [following tutorial](http://blog.crisis.net/choropleth-maps-with-node-js-and-d3-part-2/) I have managed to create a choropleth. However the choropleth I have is very static and has no legend.

So I followed [this tutorial](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/27/responsive-legends-with-d3/) and now have a legend that looks like this:

[image: map legend]

My CSV data driving the choropleth follows this structure:

[image: csv data]

**CURRENT LEGEND CODE**

```
d3.csv('data/fruit.csv', function (error, cdata) {
    var formats = {
        percent: d3.format('%'),
        thousands: d3.format('s')
    };

    var colors = d3.scale.quantize().range(colorbrewer.Greens[7]);
    colors.domain([0, d3.max(d3.values(cdata), function(d) { return d.CartCount; })]);

    var legend = d3.select('#map-legend')
        .append('ul')
            .attr('class', 'list-inline');

    // splitting of legend
    var keys = legend.selectAll('li.key')
        .data(colors.range());

    keys.enter().append('li')
        .attr('class', 'key')
        .style('border-top-color', String)
        .text(function(d) {
            var r = colors.invertExtent(d);
            return formats.thousands(r[0]);
        });
```

I would like the legend colour split to be the same, but I would like to have only 3 labels that show the cart count in thousands. So for example 2000 carts would be 2K and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the same scale that you use for the legend for determining the fill of the paths?

Comment: No, I was using a `style` attribute of `opacity` and was feeding it my opacity value from the CSV. Thinking about this further, I am thinking I can let D3 handle all that? I just feed it my cart count numbers?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to use the same scale that you're using for the legend, otherwise the colours won't match.

Comment: I just did. and I have updated my question with the new issue @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Use `.ticks()` and `.tickFormat()`.

Comment: hmm on what bit do I use `ticks()`? everywhere else they have axis, but I don't :/

Comment: You can also filter the return value of `colors.range()`, but using an axis and the functions to controlling the ticks will give you some more flexibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70143/discussion-between-ciwan-and-lars-kotthoff).